# Need driver for touch screen

Tags: touchscreen

I have a 10" touch screen for a Raspberry Pi, but the CD along with the touch controller supports only Windows CE, Fedora, SUSE and Red Hat. I tried SUSE and Fedora. The files were in script format, `.sh`.

I tried `chmod +x`, then `sh touchkit.setup_Suse90.sh`, and I got this error:

For SUSE:

```
sh touchkit.setup_suse90.sh 
: not foundtup_suse90.sh: 2: touchkit.setup_suse90.sh: 
: not foundtup_suse90.sh: 3: touchkit.setup_suse90.sh: :
: not foundtup_suse90.sh: 4: touchkit.setup_suse90.sh: :
: not foundtup_suse90.sh: 6: touchkit.setup_suse90.sh: :
: not foundtup_suse90.sh: 8: touchkit.setup_suse90.sh: :
: not foundtup_suse90.sh: 9: touchkit.setup_suse90.sh: :
: not foundtup_suse90.sh: 10: touchkit.setup_suse90.sh: :
: not foundtup_suse90.sh: 11: touchkit.setup_suse90.sh: :
: not foundtup_suse90.sh: 16: touchkit.setup_suse90.sh: 
touchkit.setup_suse90.sh: 1: touchkit.setup_suse90.sh: 
Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

For Fedora:

`bash: ./touchkit.setup_fdr.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

I need it for Wheezy, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The drivers will almost certainly be x86 specific and not usable on the Pi's ARM processor.

It'd probably be worth asking around on the rPi forums to see if anyone has had any luck, or check the wiki to see if its listed as supported.

I'm assuming you've plugged it in though to see if it 'just works', which it may well do.

You should also take a look at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com